SciPy UnivariateSpline smoothing condition
I'm using the UnivariateSpline from SciPy, and it appears to me that the second formula it gives for the smoothing condition (for the s parameter) is incorrect.
The first formula it gives to decide when to stop adding knots to the spline seems fine:
sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0) <= s

This is fine (despite the syntax not being proper Python code due to the i and using Numpy sum).
After stating the above formula, they then state, "However, because of numerical issues, the actual condition is" and give this second formula:
abs(sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0) - s) < 0.001 * s

This does not seem correct at all to me. (If you care, I'm a mathematician.) The issue is as follows. Define the error as  error = sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0)
Their second formula is saying
abs(error - s) < 0.001 * s

This is the same (mathematically speaking) as saying that
0.999 * s < error < 1.001 * s

This means that error is approximately s. Contrast this to their first formula, which is just saying error <= s.

Am I missing something, or is their second formula not really the stopping condition for smoothing?

It appears that the call to the absolute value function just shouldn't be there. Without it, my modified second formula would be equivalent to this (which makes a lot more sense to me):
error < 1.001 * s

I checked their claim on their stopping condition and found that the error is sometimes made to be outside the interval 0.999 * s < error < 1.001 * s:
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x = range(4)
y = [0.01, 1.01, 2.01, 3.01]
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=1)
print(spl(x))
print(sum((yi-spl(xi))**2 for xi, yi in zip(x,y)))    
# prints this:
#[0.01 1.01 2.01 3.01]
#3.6412113011071178e-34

I tried looking up the source code and found the UnivariateSpline class, but it appears to me that the heart of their algorithm is the call to dfitpack.fpcurf0 which I haven't found the source code for.

If you think there is an error with scipy then you should create an issue on their github.

"it appears to me that the heart of their algorithm is the call to dfitpack.fpcurf0 which I haven't found the source code for." The dfitpack.fpcurf0 is a wrapper which calls the fpcurf function, defined in this Fortran file: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/eb83a9d1a5ae209bdfb481b31f5d1121c8b57685/scipy/interpolate/fitpack/fpcurf.f#L1

I think you have a strong point here - the equation described isn't what the Fortran file is doing. Specifically, it has two exit conditions. The first is that when error < 0.999 * s, it stops adding more knots, fits the spline, then exits. (Line 173) The second is when 0.999 * s < error < 1.001 * s. In this case, it stops adding more knots, skips the spline fitting step, and exits. (Line 171) The docs describe the equation behind exit #2, but miss the much more common exit #1.

Nonetheless, I would suggest that you file an issue about this, as SO users don't have the power to fix this.

Thank you everyone for the comments. I did create an issue on GitHub.  They stated that the issue is that the documentation has a typo in it, where the 0.001 should be 1.001 instead.
